# Edit record before delete. Django DeleteView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the follow models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ....
    posts = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('numero post'), default=0)
    ....

class Post(models.Model):
    ....
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, verbose_name=_('categorie'))
    ....
```

the `Category.posts` field counts the number of the posts related to it's own category. I increase the counter into the `CreateView` in the following way:

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        ...
        categories = self.object.categories.all()
        for category in categories:
            category.posts = category.posts + 1
            category.save()

        self.object.save()
        return super(CreatePostView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Whene i delete the blog post i need to decrement the counter when the `Post` is deleted. I've tried to do in this way:

```
class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        ...
        categories = post.categories.all()
        for category in categories:
            if (category.posts - 1) > 0:
                category.posts = category.posts - 1
                category.save()
        return post
```

But it doesn't work, because the record is deleted before that this method is called.

How can i do this operation before that the record is deleted?
Or there is a built-in way to get the number of related records from `Category`?

Comment: What is the `category.posts` doing here? By this you prevent it to hit zero?

Comment: How you can see, `category.posts` is a `PositiveIntegerField` and it can be less than 0

Comment: but now it will never het zero, or negative values. So if the last post is removed, then it still will have 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `form_valid` for a `DeleteView` since a `DeleteView` has no form.

What we can do is add some logic in the `.delete(..)` function, which is the function that deletes the object. The `DeleteView` implements this as:

> ```
> def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Call the delete() method on the fetched object and then redirect to the
>     success URL.
>     """
>     self.object = self.get_object()
>     success_url = self.get_success_url()
>     self.object.delete()
>     return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
> ```

So we can implement this as:

```
from django.db.models import F

class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):

    model = Post
    # ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.post.categories.all().update(posts=F('posts')-1)
        return super(DeletePostView, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

The above will update the categories in "bulk" by decrementing the `posts` field. Here howver, it *can* reach zero (which is impossible in your given code).

If you want to prevent that, we could use [**`Greatest`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) to avoid that:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):

    model = Post
    # ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object.post.categories.all().update(posts=Greatest(F('posts')-1, Value(1)))
        return super(DeletePostView, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i get the follow error: `ValueError: "<Post: Post 1>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: But is there a built-in method to get the number of the `Post` related to each `Category`?

Comment: @masaterofnothing: I made a typo. The following normally should work.

Comment: @masaterofnothing: and yes, but here it might make sense to cache it, if you want to obtain the number of posts per category rather fast.

Comment: please, can you explain me how to get the number of posts related?

Comment: @masaterofnothing: with `my_category.post_set.count()`.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem. May I ask why you have used `self.object = self.get_object()` here instead of `somevariable = self.get_object()`. I'm asking this because this makes me think `self.object` is somehow related to the class and I cannot find any documentation reference for it.

Answer (score 5):

in version 4.0 you'll get the warning DeleteViewCustomDeleteWarning: DeleteView uses FormMixin to handle POST requests. As a consequence, any custom deletion logic in YourDeleteView.delete() handler should be moved to form_valid(). so, go ahead and implement your logic in form_valid